# Umbrella term for "batch processing (script)" and "interactive (human)"

Tags: terminology

I am searching an umbrella term for this:

- batch processing by a script. No human was involved.
- interactive. A human did it.

I need the umbrella term for naming the relevant column.

The table shows the last mails which were created by a mail handling application.

```
Date       | Subject | From  | To   | ?????
--------------------------------------------
2018-02-07 | Dear .. | me@.. | you@ | batch
2018-02-06 | Thank.. | me@.. | you@ | human
2018-02-05 | New Foo | me@.. | you@ | human
....
```

Comment: Can you give example sentences where the missing word you’re searching for is marked by XXX? As it stands it’s not clear whether you’re looking for nouns, adjectives etc.

Comment: @MattBecker82 I updated the question. I hope it is clear now, please ask if something is missing. Thank you.

Comment: @Davo it is the GUI of an email application. Sorry I  have no sentences for this use case.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you’re looking for a label to signify the _category_ of whether an email was generated interactively by a human, or via an automated batch process. I can’t think of a single word specifically for this but you could use more generic terms such as _initiator_ or _originator_. Possibly adding _type_ to either of these too.

Comment: "Mode", "method", "actor", "agent", "workflow", "Create a Willy Wonka meme re Augustus Gloop: my chocolate must never be touched by human hands!"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ask on a software site.

Comment: Heading 'Manual' with entries Yes or No.

Comment: Naming, including naming computer objects such as columns, is off topic here. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Davo Avoid answers in comments. See: [Privileges > Comment Everywhere – Help Center](https://chat.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), [Is SE enforcing “no answers in comments”? – Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10646/)

Comment: @user662852 See above.

Comment: @RossMurray See above.

Answer (score 2):

As both actions appear to involve processing, one by machine and one by person, you could use as a column heading:

> Processing Mode

or, if you are short of space, just

> Mode

However, I am not sure that the two events are of the same type. A machine can work in either batch or single mode, and a human is always involved to press the button. So it seems to me that the logical alternatives are actually:

> *Processing Mode:* batch v. single

or

> *Processing:* machine v. human
>
> *Operation:* machine v. human

It appears from your description that you should replace ‘batch’ by ‘machine’ and use either ‘processing’ or ‘operation’ as your header.

Answer (score 1):

**Actor**. If the program you are using was specified with a [use case model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case), then both the script *and* the human user are actors playing a role in a use case.

Comment: But it’s for a GUI. Will the human viewing it know about use cases and actors?

Comment: @David Good point.  In looking at the report format, I assumed it would be for a more technical user looking at a log or some kind of terminal display.  But I could be wrong.